# Angular mat-menu

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I want to make a big matmenu (95 items) but it goes over the page.

see my code :

```html
<mat-menu #departements="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="choix_du_departement(01)" >01</button>
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="choix_du_departement(02)" >02</button>
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="choix_du_departement(03)">03</button>
...
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="choix_du_departement(95)">95</button>
</mat-menu>
```

I tried to manage via .scss
with

```css
 .mat-menu{
   max-height: 50px;
 }
```

but nothing change

I tried to modify .mat-menu-item too but some it goes off the page

Answer (score 2):

If I understand, you need to set the height of the button

```
 .mat-menu-item{
   max-height: 50px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options either give your `mat-menu` element a mat-menu class 
Or change your CSS selector to  `mat-menu` instead of  `.mat-menu`

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with getting this css applied also, instead I wrapped the content in a div with a custom class and set the height of that div.

Answer (score 0):

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane {
        max-height: 350px !important;
      }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not welcome. Please describe what this code improves, what it does.